# In PrimeNG, how do I open a p-dialog to the exact dimensions of an image?

Tags: angular, image, dialog, primeng, angular14

I'm using PrimeNG 14 with Angular 14.  I would like to open a dialog to the exact size of a downloaded image, but not quite sure how to size a dialog dynamically.  Currently I have

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="showDialog" [style]="{width: '450px'}" header="My Image" [modal]="true"
 styleClass="p-fluid">
    <img  
        id="myImage"
        [src]="myImage" />
</p-dialog>
```

In which I download my image using

```
  this.myService.getFile(this.myId).subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      const blob = new Blob([response], { type: response.type });
      this.imageSize = this.formatBytes(blob.size);
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      this.myImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
  this.showDialog = true;
    },
    error: (error: Error) => {
      console.log(error);
      console.error("image download error occurred.");
    }
  });
```

Is there any way to dynamically determine the size of my image and then open the dialog to those dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you remove fixed width from dialog component - it'll fit content inside it.

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-fl6tpg?file=src/app/app.component.html) (stackblitz).